# SSRS How to repeat rectangle on each page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a large rectangle which includes a smaller rectangle (I use this as the page header), as well as a text box, and a tablix. They are laid out in that order- Rectangle at top, text box in middle, tablix at bottom. Is there any way to repeat the top rectangle, as well as the text box on each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as you describe. The easiest way to get a page header on your report is to add one! Simply right-click anywhere on the workspace background and then click "Add Page Header" (if you're using Visual Studio you can also get to this from the "Report" menu, or the "Insert" tab in the Report Builder application) now drag your rectangle and textbox into the new header.